# .Net 4.0 App not working with .Net 4.0 control added as a reference

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have a .Net 4.0 app that I wrote that uses a .Net 4.0 control that I also wrote.

I have two XP systems.   Both have .Net 4.0 installed.  The app was crashing on both XP systems with an error at startup saying the application has encountered a problem.  Runs fine on Windows 7.

If I just remove the code that references my control the app still crashes.  If I remove the reference entirely then the app starts up fine.

So on one of the systems I installed VS 2010 Basic Express to compile the app under XP.   After the install both the XP compiled app and the original windows 7 compiled app ran fine with the control installed on the PC that had VS 2010 Basic installed.  But neither ran on the XP without VS 2010.

So it seems the VS2010 installed something, the question is what?

A little about the app.

Complied for Win32 using .Net 4.0

Compiled with VS2010 VBASIC Express

A little about the control

Compiled with VS2010 C++ Express

Compiled for win32 using 4.0

Toolset Platform v100

A little about the static library used by the .Net control

Compiled with VS2010 C++Express

Compiled for win32 using 4.0

Toolset Platform v100

Uses the STD Static library.

Could it be that Platform Toolset v100 just needs to be installed on the XP system?   Where do I find it?   I have searched everywhere.

Anyway to know the actual cause of that crash?

It is actually a .Net wrapper for a C++ library

Comment: are you sure it is a ".Net 4.0" dll and not a ".Net 4.0 Client Framework" dll (silverlight)

Comment: Yes I am sure I have compiled for .Net 4.0 and not Client Framework.

Comment: As I have mentioned the app runs just fine as long as my control is not referenced.

Comment: try adding an Application.UnhandledException handler to your app (program.cs) ans show exception and stack trace. That should get you more info. I've seen things like this in the past on XP, it was a bad Framework install, had to them all off and start again. Installing VS2010 could eaily be squaring something up.

Comment: "It crashes" is not an appropriate problem description.  You can get good diagnostics out of the AppDomain.UnhandledException event.  Post the exception message and the stack trace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just used the .Net 2.0 version of my control and got the app compiled under 2.0/  Still curious as to what caused the issue above.